# Why @CreatedDate is not valid in @ElementCollection

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a question, which has been bothering me for some time.

I tried to use `@createdDate` in the following code, but it doesn't work at all.

Java version: JDK 19
Spring boot version: 3.0.2
Jpa version: 3.0.2
Hibernate.core version: 6.1.6.Final

User.java

```java
@Table(name = "sys_user")
@DynamicUpdate

@Getter
//@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
//@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public final class User {
    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserId id;

    @Embedded
    private AuditingTime auditingTime = new AuditingTime();
    @Embedded
    private AuditingUser auditingUser = new AuditingUser();

//    @Getter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)

//  **THIS HERE**
    @ElementCollection
    private final Set<Password> passwords = new HashSet<>();

//    @Getter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)

//  **THIS HERE**
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable
    private final Set<RoleItem> roleItems = new HashSet<>();

    @Getter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Transient
    private transient final List<UserEvent> domainEvent = new ArrayList<>();

    public static User of(CreateUserCommand command) {
        User user = new User(
                UserIdGenerator.newId(),
                command.getUsername(),
                command.getEmail(),
                command.getExpiredTime());
        ValidationUtils.validate(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

RoleItem.java

```java
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class RoleItem {
    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    private Long roleId;

//  **THIS HERE**
    @CreatedBy
    private Long createdBy;
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;


    public static RoleItem of(CreateRoleItemCommand command) {
        RoleItem roleItem = new RoleItem(command.getRoleId());
        ValidationUtils.validate(roleItem);
        return roleItem;
    }
}
```

JpaConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class JpaConfig {
    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<Long> auditorAware() {
        return () -> Optional.of(1L);
    }
}
```

At first I thought it was a problem with the private constructor.

I tried setting all constructors to Public, but to no avail.

After that I thought there was an error in my code and I tried to use `@OneToMany` and it worked.

```java
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn
    private final Set<RoleItem> roleItems = new HashSet<>();
```

But what I want is the `value object` form.

Then I tried to remove the final, which also didn't work.

I don't know why.

I want the audit function to be available in `@ElementCollection`

Answer (score -1):

From a technical perspective:

An element collection does not contain entities. Therefore life cycle events don't get triggered for them.
But the auditing feature which fills `@CreatedDate` and similar attribute is based on life cycle events and therefore does not work for entries in an element collection.

From a more abstract perspective:

The content of an element collection does not have an identity there for created and modification date doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand what you mean. However, imagine if a user adds a role, but there is no record of when it was added and who added it, wouldn't that be dangerous? How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Make it a proper entity